# numberformat exception using alarmamanager - crashes before on start

Tags: android, gps

---------UPDATE  -----------------------------------------

When the app starts I receive numberformat exception at line :

```
final long thetime=Long.parseLong(time_value);
```

But the above aren't in the main activity...

In the xml file I have in the edittex

> android:inputType="number" .

This line is in myservice class in which I have the alarmamanager(note I can't use catch because below(alarm.setRepeating) it doesn't recognize "thetime" value.

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //try{
            String time_value;
            time_value=(String) intent.getStringExtra("time_value");
            final long thetime=Long.parseLong(time_value);// }
        //  catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            //}
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        mHandler.post(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // Start service using AlarmManager
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
                Intent intent = new Intent(myservice.this,selection.class);
                PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(myservice.this, 0, intent,
                        0);
                AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                        thetime*1000, pintent);
             // Tell the user about what we did.
                Toast.makeText(myservice.this, "Configured time interval",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I load the time_value from another activity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btn:
             edit11=edit1.getText().toString();
             edit22=edit2.getText().toString();
             Intent i=new Intent(this,selection.class);
             i.putExtra("code_value",edit11);
             Intent k=new Intent(this,myservice.class);
             k.putExtra("time_value",edit22);
             this.startService(k);
             Intent l=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(l);  
             break;

     }
     }
```

Comment: what problem u are getting with current code?

Comment: @prasperK:It doesn't seem to update the position every time_value I input.Also , I can't know if the data are passed to the http.

Comment: and u want to use alarmmanager for getting current location and send it to server ? then create an intentservice .start intentservice using alarmmanager and inside IntentService first find user location then send it to server

Comment: @prasperK:I have the location.I am getting it from this class (selection)using LatLng(i didn't put all the  code) .I just want this location to be updated every time intervals.that's why I use alarmmanager but I don't know if sth missing from alarmmanager.

Comment: just make ur code using intentservice. you will need to put location and server related code inside  intentservice

Comment: @prasperK:Doesn't these lines do that also ? Intent intent = new Intent(selection.this, selection.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(selection.this, 0, intent,
                0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Comment: @prasperK:Ok, I updated but still the same.But maybe is the constructor fro getIntent. (please check update2 above).Also,what about the data being passed to hhtp?Is it ok?Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had forgot the :

startService() im my main activity.
I had to put it in myservice activity.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

```
because I made lonfitude and latitude Strings (I had them as double before). How can I overcome that?
```

To get String from double use `String.valueOf();`

```
String latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
```

Repeat

```
Also,how can I select to send the data in time intervals that the user will define?
```

To repeat at specific interval use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Comment: :Can you tell me how to implement alarmmanager?Also , with the above code i postdata to a http but how to get GPS location every specific time interval and send the data to http every this interval?

Answer (score 0):

```
how can I select to send the data in time intervals that the user will define
```

You can use [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html). Take the user input for time interval and pass it to [schedule()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) of Timer. Thing that should be taken into consideration is when app is closed or user changes time interval then cancel previous TimerTask and purge Timer, if any.

For Alarm, do the following in your activity class:

```
PendingIntent Sender = null;
        Intent AlarmIntent = new Intent("com.example.gpstrackdemo.RECEIVEALARM");
        AlarmManager AlmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(GpsTrackActivity.this, 0,
                AlarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0, 15 * 60 * 1000,
                Sender);
```

AlarmIntent is the intent for [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). Here is its code:

```
public class StartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
private static final String TAG = "StartServiceReceiver";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyLocationService.class);
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
    Log.v(TAG, "onReceive called");
}
}
```

On receiving the broadcast, it will start Location service, in which we will get current location of user.

Service Class:

```
public class MyLocationService extends Service implements
    OnLocationReceivedListener {

private LocationManager manager;
private Location location = null;
PowerManager powerManager;
private WakeLock wakeLock;
private String country;
GPSLocationListener mGPSLocationListener;
NetworkLocationListener mNetworkLocationListener;
private static final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 250;
private static String TAG = "MyLocationService";
LocTimerTask mTimerTask;
int mSattelites;
Timer myLocTimer;
int count = 0;
boolean isGPS;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onStartCommand called");
    getCurrentLocation();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.v(TAG, "onCreate called");
    powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "mywakelock");
    mGPSLocationListener = new GPSLocationListener();
    mNetworkLocationListener = new NetworkLocationListener();
    wakeLock.acquire();
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void getCurrentLocation() {
    manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    manager.addGpsStatusListener(mGPSStatusListener);
    mTimerTask = new LocTimerTask(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Log.v(TAG, "GPS ENABLED");
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L,
                50.0f, mGPSLocationListener);
    }

    if(manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000L,
                50.0f, mNetworkLocationListener);
    }

    myLocTimer = new Timer("LocationRunner", true);
    myLocTimer.schedule(mTimerTask, 0, 500);
}

public class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location argLocation) {
        location = argLocation;
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }
}

public class NetworkLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location argLocation) {
        location = argLocation;
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }
}
class LocTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    String provider;

    public LocTimerTask(String provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            count++;
            Log.v(TAG, "Timer Task run" + i);
            location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if (location != null) {
                Log.v(TAG, "in timer task run in if location not null");
                onLocationReceived(location);
                myLocTimer.cancel();
                myLocTimer.purge();
                mTimerTask.cancel();
                return;
            } else {
                isGPS = false;
                if (location == null && count == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                    turnGPSOff();
                    location = manager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {

                        onLocationReceived(location);
                        myLocTimer.cancel();
                        myLocTimer.purge();
                        mTimerTask.cancel();
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    };

    public void run() {
        mHandler.post(r);
    }
}

private GpsStatus.Listener mGPSStatusListener = new GpsStatus.Listener() {

    @Override
    public synchronized void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        switch (event) {
        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
            GpsStatus status = manager.getGpsStatus(null);
            mSattelites = 0;
            Iterable<GpsSatellite> list = status.getSatellites();
            for (GpsSatellite satellite : list) {
                if (satellite.usedInFix()) {
                    mSattelites++;
                }
            }
            break;

        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
            break;

        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
            break;

        case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (myLocTimer != null) {
        myLocTimer.cancel();
        myLocTimer.purge(); //Timer not required any more
    }

    if (mTimerTask != null) {
        if (mTimerTask.r != null) {
            mTimerTask.mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTimerTask.r);
        }
    }

    if (manager != null) {
        if (mGPSLocationListener != null) {
            manager.removeUpdates(mGPSLocationListener);
        }

        //remove location updates for listener once your work is done, otherwise it will drain battery
        if (mNetworkLocationListener != null) {
            manager.removeUpdates(mNetworkLocationListener);
        }

        if (mGPSStatusListener != null) {
            manager.removeGpsStatusListener(mGPSStatusListener);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationReceived(Location mLoc) {
    //Send data to http server once you get location.
}
}
```

Here my service class implements a listener which have a callback method `onLocationReceived` in which you can do your stuff after you get location.

```
public interface OnLocationReceivedListener {
    public void onLocationReceived(Location mLoc);
}
```

And in your manifest, declare broadcast receiver and service respectively:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".receiver.StartServiceReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.gpstrackdemo.RECEIVEALARM" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
<service android:name=".service.MyLocationService"
        android:enabled="true"></service>
```

Comment: :Can you tell me how to implement alarmmanager?Also , with the above code i postdata to a http but how to get GPS location every specific time interval and send the data to http every this interval?

Comment: :Thanks a lot for your help but you present another way to receive a location.I want to use thw way I have for getting the location.I just want to handle the alarmmanager in my code.Thanks again

Comment: No problem, use only AlarmManager in your activity class to start your service.

Comment: :I am trying to do that.As you see (i updated) I use another class "myservice" where I have the alarmmanager ,but I receive a nnullpointer..

Comment: Where did you started your service? Make sure you have sent extra value with intent.

Comment: I start my service from another activity :  Intent k=new Intent(this,myservice.class);
        k.putExtra("time_value",edit22);
        this.startService(k);